# Do you know a good Java RSS/Feed Generator?

Tags: java, rss, generator, feed

I'm searching a small **Java** based RSS/Feed Generator, something like the [FeedCreator.class.php](http://www.bitfolge.de/rsscreator-en.html) library, any suggestions?, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's the Rome framework as well

http://rometools.github.io/rome/

Does RSS and Atom

Comment: This is the one I ended up using, thanks!

Comment: Sadly, looks like rometools.org has had it's domain expire- but a bit of digging finds http://rometools.github.io/rome/

Answer (score 3):

How about [jRSS](http://jrss.sourceforge.net/)? It looks promising -- supports generating RSS 2 and is relatively small.

Answer (score 2):

I used an API a few years back called [ROME](https://rome.dev.java.net/). I thought it was a breeze to set up and get going with.

Answer (score 2):

i used [Informa](http://informa.sourceforge.net/) with success. especially useful if you plan to support multiple verison of rss (0.9-2.0) reasonable sized library , well documented.

a quite complete list con be found at http://java-source.net/open-source/rss-rdf-tools